# Spring validation - avoid duplicate constraint messages

Tags: java, spring, validation

New Spring developer here.  I have searched SO and the spring docs but can't figure this out.

I am trying to use Spring Validation to apply any applicable `Validator` implementations to an arbitrary object by ctor injecting all registered validators and iterating through them calling `supports()` and then conditionally `validate()`.   This works, except it produces duplicate validation messages because the JSR-303 constraint annotations are validated twice - once by `jsr303Validator` and again by `mvcValidator`.

I tried calling all validators and removing duplicate errors afterwards, but the `equals()` implementation on `ObjectError` doesn't work as desired (it leaves entries with the same error code and message).

Validator implemenation:

```
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

@Service
class ObjectValidatorImpl {
    private final Validator[] validators;

    public ObjectValidatorImpl(Validator[] validators) {
        this.validators = validators;
    }

    public void validate(Object obj) throws BindException {
        // Container for holding any validation errors that are found
        BindException errors = new BindException(obj, obj.getClass().getName());

        for (Validator validator : validators) {
            if (validator.supports(obj.getClass())) {
                validator.validate(obj, errors);
            }
        }

        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            throw errors;
        }
    }
}
```

Example program showing error:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ValidationTestApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectValidator objectValidator;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ValidationTestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        try {
            objectValidator.validate(new TestObject());
        }
        catch (BindException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}

class TestObject {
    @NotEmpty
    String name;
}
```

Example error output:

```
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'validationtest.TestObject' on field 'name': rejected value [null]; codes [NotEmpty.validationtest.TestObject.name,NotEmpty.name,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [validationtest.TestObject.name,name]; arguments []; default message [name]]; default message [may not be empty]
Field error in object 'validationtest.TestObject' on field 'name': rejected value [null]; codes [NotEmpty.validationtest.TestObject.name,NotEmpty.name,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [validationtest.TestObject.name,name]; arguments []; default message [name]]; default message [may not be empty]
```

Note that the 'name cannot be empty' error is reported twice, by both `jsr303Validator` and by `mvcValidator`.

Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime("com.h2database:h2")
}
```

What is the correct (most Springy?) way to resolve this type of situation?  It feels like it is a classpath configuration problem and I should avoid having both validators in the same project, but this code is in a shared library that may or may not be used with Spring Web MVC, and I am not sure how to prevent this.

Comment: some code will be helpful to understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what should happen?

You have multiple validators registered for the object, and so when you loop over all of them, and ask for validation messages, you get duplicates since both of them are similar.

Comment: It might be what should happen, but it is not what I want to happen.  The question could be rephrased as how do I avoid having multiple JSR303 validators registered when using Spring Web?  I am not explicitly registering the validators so I am not sure why there are two JSR303 validators or how to avoid this.

Comment: That's fair. Are you auto wiring those validators? They serve different purposes. I believe the mvc  one is what will allow binding the form to the messages. You could just discard one of the validators, but they may do different things in the future (if someone else adds a custom one).

Comment: I'm not explicitly autowiring any validators.  I think just including `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web` registers the MVC validator.  I wanted to avoid hard-coding logic to exclude the MVC validator (e.g. by class name) because that seems brittle as you point out.  I was looking for a way to control what's injected or at least run - basically I want the standard JSR303 validator (`LocalValidatorFactoryBean`) and any application-specific custom validators.  I'm just not sure how to filter the list of injected validators to those (or choose a better approach).

Comment: It doesn't really seem like this should happen, but i still dont understand who is setting that list of validators you have. [According to this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1539) it seems like you should only get one if you go through the factory. If two are registered, it should be throwing an exception. sorry to not be more help